# Excel Formula to calculate number of user hits in a system everyday

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

This is the continuation of my previous questions and I have included my global aim with project.

Excel Link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5W4CgZKsARFSmhqV0ZSM1lBSkE/view?usp=sharing

**Task:**
The task is to collect the "number hits" of a user in an application "on each day". I can collect a log from the system which will give me the name of the users and their last hit date and total number of hits.(This total number of hits in not on daily basis, but sum of all days). and I need to make a formula to segregate these on daily basis

**Screenshot:**
To understand in better way I have created few screenshot, which I am looking to implement.

The excel has two tabs **raw_data** and **value_capture**. I will use raw_data to paste my raw data collecting from system log and value_capture to generate day by day hit statistics

Raw_data tab:
It has three details, 1. date. 2. name and 3 totals hits(This total hits are overall hits of that user on all days)

[image]

value_capture:
This has all user names and all dates to mark each day and a column to display all hits.

[image]

Now, considering an example of date 20141120, all users hits are 0.
raw_data shows 0 against all users

[image]

so value_capture are has to be updated with same

[image]

Now on next day 20141121, there is some hits against some users. (Note : if there is no hit against a user, it will only the previous date ie,date will update only if there is a hit on that day)

[image]

value_capture updated with that details

[image]

On 20141122, there are some more hits against the users

[image]

value_capture updated with the details. since the raw_data will show total number of hits against a user, the way of calculating on a particular will be **total hits- previous date hit**

[image]

I am stuck at a way to develop the excel formula here.Looking for an idea to implement this.

**Note :** 
Users name will be fixed on both tabs, but that may come in different order in raw_data tab.

**UPDATE**

My raw_data sheet will be updated everyday and I want my  formula results be fixed in the value_capture sheet after the values are updated (removed) from sheet raw_data

Comment: Paste each day's data at the end of the existing data, sort by user then date (ascending). Add a formula starting from D2 `=IF(B2=B1,C2-C1,C2)` and fill down.  Then create a pivot table from Cols A,B and D

Comment: @acr did you forget to put in your question that your raw_data sheet is updated everyday and you want your formula results be fixed in the value_capture sheet after the values are updated (removed) from sheet raw_data? am i right? or did you just change the processing strategy?

Comment: I feel like this data would be better in a pivot table...

Comment: @AHC          : Yes, I forgot to specify that.. updated my question

Comment: @AHC :         This is my overall implementation plan.

Comment: If you're going to be clearing the source data each day then your only real option is to use VBA for this.

Comment: @teylyn        here is structure

Comment: @acr another ambiguity: supposing you change/update raw_data everyday. So in column A of raw_data you may happen to store several dates prior to today's date,ok? now what happens to your SECOND row in value_capture sheet? How do you update the dates in that row? manually? or pulling them from date column of the other sheet? AND most important is: what is the MAX number of dates that can be stored in the SECOND row of the value_capture sheet? not a year i suppose, if you go month by month, then you should have value_capture_november, value_capture_december, etc. right? how is it organized?

Comment: @AHC           when I implement this, I am going to take the oldest date from my raw_date to update value_capture sheet. (There wont be much difference between the oldest date and current date, max 3-4 days). My plan is to keep a month details in value_capture and old date is going to save as PDF archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as i mentioned in my answer to your previous question, the only way to **save the results of a formula after deleting/removing its reference cells**, is to use a **macro**.

***First of all***

you need a proper formula to pull the data from the *raw_data* sheet and then calculate the difference between that particular cell  where the formula resides and the sum of previous cells in that row.
we need two formulas:
**one for the** ***column B*** of your *value_capture* sheet. 
and the **second one for** ***the rest of your table***. why? because in the first column you don't calculate the difference between itself and the previous cells, because there aren't any. So there is a little difference in the formula.
***FORMULA ONE:***(paste in **B3** and drag and fill down)

```
=SUMIFS(raw_data!$C:$C;raw_data!$B:$B;$A3;raw_data!$A:$A;B$2)
```

***FORMULA TWO:***(paste in **C3** and drag and fill down and to the right)

`=IF(SUMIFS(raw_data!$C:$C;raw_data!$B:$B;$A3;raw_data!$A:$A;C$2)-IF(ISNUMBER(B3);SUM($B3:B3);0)>0;SUMIFS(raw_data!$C:$C;raw_data!$B:$B;$A3;raw_data!$A:$A;C$2)-IF(ISNUMBER(B3);SUM($B3:B3);0);0)`

As you see in my screenshot for user in cell **A3**, we have value of **4** for the date **20141120** and the next day the value is **14** but the cell gets the difference, that is **10**, and then then next day, the value increases to **16**, so the cell value for **D3** becomes **2** which is the different of 16 for that day and the sum of previous ones. This continues until **today's** value which is **24** so the cell gets **7** because the sum of previous ones is **17**.
[image]

Now that you have your values captured correctly, with respect to the difference with the sum of previous days, it is time to make them fixed and eternal.
**For this you need a macro:**

```
Sub saveMyData()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Range("B3:L18").Copy

ws.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

So obviously you need to update this range **"B3:L18"** this is what I have in the example sheet only.

Now this macro, **copies** and **pastes** all the values from that range *onto* itself, so you lose your formulas.
So each day, you need to go to *line 21** of the same sheet and get the formula from **C21** and paste it on somewhere on **row 3** from where you want to continue capturing the new day's data. (you won't need the first formula, because it is only used once in the first column, the first day.)
This was the only way to capture the values using formulas and then save the results of the formulas in their place and go and fetch new data. 
I couldn't think of any other strategy to make it more automatic, except for writing mova VBA and letting excel go and find where you left the day before and paste the formulas in their right place and repeat the task.

***all these formulas are array formulas, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formulas.***

***Remember to adjust the formulas to your regional settings, i suppose, by replacing the ";" with ",".***

[here is the example sheet downloadable from this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nsh6szw4ufs3x5i/sumif_fixed_values_OK.xlsm?dl=0)

 Tell me if you have problems anywhere and don't forget to answer my question in the comments about the way you update your dates in row 2 of value_capture.

Comment: Thanks for helping me here. The one problem which I forgot is that, in a day I may upload the raw data more than onetime. so there is chance that a user may come and hit and that will update the hit count after my first data upload to raw sheet. since this method, going to clear the formula in value_capture, next time when I run script on same day it will not work. so the best way will be checking the VBA. I dont have knowledge in VBA, but I will check the basics. Appreciate if you can give me some formula hints that can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

The formula that you are looking for is SUMIFS

```
=SUMIFS([SUM RANGE],[RANGE 1],[VALUE 1],[RANGE 2],[VALUE 2])
```

SUM RANGE is the column of values that you want to SUM so that is your column C. For Range 1 you want to select the range of IDs. The VALUE 1 will be equal to the value in Column A Row X. For RANGE 2 it will be the Date column. For VALUE 2 it will be the value in the column header.

Put this together and you have something akin to:

```
 =SUMIFS(raw_data!$C:$C,raw_data!$B:$B,$A3,raw_data!$A:$A,B$2)
```

This would be in cell B3 and you could fill the other cells from there.

If total hits for a day is a rolling count of ALL hits ever then at the end of your equation you need to subtract the sum of the prior days.

For example:

```
 =SUM(B3:B4)
```

This would only need to be added to subsequent columns (not the first).

So the equation in C3 would be

```
=SUMIFS(raw_data!$C:$C,raw_data!$B:$B,$A3,raw_data!$A:$A,C$2)-SUM(B$3:C3)
```

Then in D3 it becomes

```
=SUMIFS(raw_data!$C:$C,raw_data!$B:$B,$A3,raw_data!$A:$A,D$2)-SUM(B$3:D3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sumifs](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/SUMIFS-function-9dd6179e-cced-41dd-ac38-08fdf5b929e5?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE) formula

```
=SUMIFS(raw_data!$C:$C,raw_data!$B:$B,$A3,raw_data!$A:$A,B$2)-IF(ISNUMBER(A3),A3,0)
```

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.